# Is there any way to move whats app from phone memory to sd card?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, whatsapp-messenger, app2sd

I'm using a *Samsung Galaxy fit GTS5670* running on Android 2.3.6. After installing *Whatsapp Messenger* of 13.36 MB, it was installed to phone memory. I got a total of 180 MB internal storage, and just 3.3 MB left.

Is there any way to move Whatsapp from phone memory to SDCard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I store Android apps on my SD card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-can-i-store-android-apps-on-my-sd-card)

Comment: Not quite. Topic matches, but on a quick glance I miss the crucial argument there: WA uses GCM, and for that probably requires to be notified on `BOOT_COMPLETED` – which doesn't work when installed on SD card (at least not in GB – not sure whether that changed with KK/LP). // Recommended reading: our [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) (I've just added that tag to the question).

Answer (score 2):

The newer Android versions already support moving the app from internal SD to an external. It should be in Settings->Applications->Manage Applications.